# is it possible to assign an bean id to spring integration inbound adapter with DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

assigning id with SI XML is simple as below

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
        channel="ftpChannel" session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
        filename-pattern="*.txt" auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="false" remote-directory="${remotedir}"
        local-directory="/apps/wfg/ftp/test" auto-startup="true">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000">
            <int:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
        </int:poller>
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Can the same be done in the dsl code as well below  ?

```
IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
        .from(Ftp
            .inboundAdapter(csf)
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
            .remoteDirectory(feed.getRemoteDirectory())
            .regexFilter(feed.getRegexFilter())
            .deleteRemoteFiles(feed.getDeleteRemoteFiles())
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(
                feed.getAutoCreateLocalDirectory())
            .localFilenameExpression(
                feed.getLocalFilenameExpression()).get();
```

Also can the same transitional synchronization be done in this case .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(sessionFactory())
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .remoteDirectory("ftpSource")
                .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                .localFilename(f -> f.toUpperCase() + ".a")
                .localDirectory(getTargetLocalDirectory()),
        e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter")
              .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)
                    .transactionSynchronizationFactory(syncFactory())))
        .channel(out)
        .get();
```

Comment: Thanks @gary-russell for this . looks to be problem with my IDE content assist (couldn't get the api functions ) I asked the silly question , will look at the consumer spec before posting .